# Struct Pointer typecasting error Assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
typedef struct data
{
        long open;
        long high;
        long low;
        long close;
}ohlcstruct;

ohlcstruct * pOhlc = NULL;
pOhlc = calloc(1,sizeof(pOhlc)*375);
SetPfData(sPFName,1,(long)pOhlc); //This sets the param value of sPFName as (long OHLC)
```

I am accepting the value on the other side

```
ohlcstruct * pohlctemp;     
pohlctemp = GetPfData(sPfName,1); //Getting the param set at index 1 above
//Error here
```

Error is Assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Please help

Comment: Read the warning/error messages carefully. You're trying to put a pointer into an integer without casting it as such. Presumably whatever magic function `SetPFData` is, is returning a pointer while you declared `pohlctemp` as an integer. You're trying to store said pointer from `SetPFData` inside `pohlctemp`.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] . Specifically, what does `GetPfData` return?

Answer (score 0):

When you stored the pointer with `SetPfData`, you cast the pointer to `long`. You need to do the opposite when you retrieve it with `GetPfData`, casting the result back to a pointer:

```
pohlctemp = (ohlcstruct *)GetPfData(sPfName, 1);
```

This seems like a very poor API, as there's no guarantee that a `long` can hold all pointer values.

Comment: Do i typecast it as `pohlctemp = (void *)(long)GetPfData(sPfName,1);` or 
`pohlctemp = (ohlcstruct *)(long)GetPfData(sPfName,1);`

Comment: No, you do it exactly as I wrote.